# Underlining an item

Tags: itemize, description

Is there a way to allow a new item inside an underline command? In my real work, I have a custom command generating the "item" with its text, so moving the `\underline` to the other side of the `\item` isn't an option. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\underline{\item abcd}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

The error message I get is "Something's wrong - perhaps a missing \item".

Edit: Here's a less minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\course}[3]{\item[MATH #1] \emph{#2}\newline{#3}}

\newcommand{\sixten}{\course{610}{A Course Title}{A long description \lipsum[5]}}
\newcommand{\sixtwenty}{\course{620}{Another Course Title}{A shorter description}}

\begin{document}

{\large Course Offerings:}

Fall 2016
\begin{description}
\sixten
\sixtwenty
\end{description}

Spring 2017
\begin{description}
\underline{\sixten}
\sixtwenty
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd like to underline both. In my main document I'm using the description environment, but I figured itemize would be easier to generalize for others.

Comment: It matters if you are using `description` because then you are probably passing `\item` an argument. Is that right? That's rather different from the `\item` case in `\itemize`. The point is, you can't make this work just as it is, so something has to give and it matters what can give, for that reason.

Comment: You could have an optional argument or you could have a star. If that would be an acceptable interface, it will probably be easier and more robust than trying to make the syntax above work. (The only way I can currently think to do that is to make `\underline` issue `\item` and then set `\item` to `\relax` while processing its argument. But @Bernard probably has something much more elegant in mind.)

Comment: @cfr: I don't have whatever in mind this time. Actually I think this would be very bad typography – a part of our activity here is devoted to some sort of *typotherapy* ;o)

Comment: @Bernard I agree. However, this smells like a requirement to me. How many LaTeX users use underlining voluntarily? Maybe I'm wrong, but I would have thought not very many. I always forget that `\underline` is even a standard command. EDIT: Then again...

Comment: Not a requirement, but I couldn't think of a better way to highlight something that already has bold and italics and would be printed in black and white. A better highlighting scheme would be a valid suggestion here!

Comment: A bullet is already a sort of highlighting, in my opinion. All the more so as, in English typography, lists have rather large indentation and vertical spacing. Highlighting too many parts of a text  in many different ways may result in a confusing aspect of your document.

Comment: replaced underline with `\fbox{\parbox{\textwidth}{\sixten}}`; now the box cuts through the label.

Comment: More seriously, a vertical bar between the bullet and the body of the item would be a simple highlighting. The `framed` package allows to do that, even in case of page breaks, if I remember well.

Comment: Perfect. The environment is `leftbar`.

Comment: @Bernard I hope you don't mind that I used your idea to write my own answer. Also, my code could use improvement, especially in terms of explanatory comments.

Comment: Not at all. We'll be able to compare our ideas. B. t. w.,  are grey lines considered as coloured, from your point of view?

Comment: There are legitimate reaons to use underline though. Precisely because it's not nice in the final version, it can be used to indicate changes in a pdf.  I've seen journal publishers require it for example. That of course is almost but not quite entirely iincompatible with bullet points.Their method for removing it in the final typesetting process is presumably some trivial automation followed by a manual fix, so any solution for use in that case would have to be quite simple.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I propose this, with the help of the `framed` package, slightly tweaking the `leftbar` environment. If you don't want grey lines, it's easy to remove the colour. Using `xparse`, I define a `\course` command, with $3$ mandatory arguments. A star version adds a left bar that can beak across pages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{framed, xcolor, xparse}

\renewenvironment{leftbar}{%
  \def\FrameCommand{{\hspace{20pt}\color{lightgray}\vrule width 2pt}\hspace{-18pt}}%
  \MakeFramed {\advance\hsize-2\width \FrameRestore}}%
 {\endMakeFramed}

\DeclareDocumentCommand\course{ s m m +m }{%
\item[MATH #2] \emph{#3}\newline{%
\IfBooleanTF{#1}{\setlength\OuterFrameSep{-\topsep} \begin{leftbar}#4\end{leftbar}}%
{#4}}%
}

\newcommand{\sixtwenty}{\course{620}{Another Course Title}{A shorter description}}

\begin{document}

{\large Course Offerings:}\bigskip

Fall 2016
\begin{description}
\course*{610}{A Course Title}{A long description \lipsum[5]}
\sixtwenty
\end{description}

Spring 2017
\begin{description}

\course{610}{A Course Title}{A long description \lipsum[5]}
\sixtwenty
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You need a paragraph break after the Course Offerings thing. (I know it is in the original, but there's no need to repeat it, I guess.)

Comment: The idea was to have it only be highlighted sometimes, not always. I want to be able to highlight the courses I'm thinking of taking in a future semester, then perhaps return to the document next year, change my mind, and easily change which are highlighted. I do prefer the leftbar over a box, though, and the light grey looks nice.

Comment: @dejongbrent: I've redefined the `\course` command  with `xparse`, allowing for a star version that displays the left bar.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a way of drawing the left bar suggested by Bernard when a star is appended to the command. It requires defining new courses with `\newcourse` rather than `\newcommand`, but it involves less typing as an added bonus.

- `\newcourse{\newcommandname}{<number>}{<title>}{<description>}` sets up a new course. It will create `\newcommandname` which will create the regular print of the course and `\newcommandname*` which will add a left bar in the margin.
- `\setlength\courselinewidth{<width>}` controls the width of the line.
- The colour and opacity of the line can be set with `\coursehighlight[<colour>]{<% opacity>}`. The default colour is black. Below, I show how to set the opacity and colour in a couple of ways, including one which is there just in case you get a colour printer and fancy a change.

Note that this will not work in the case that a page break occurs during the highlighted course, and no attempt is made to prevent or detect this.

Here are three examples:

[image: black line]

[image: grey and blue lines]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,tikz,tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcounter{hcourse}
\setcounter{hcourse}{0}
\newcommand{\course}[3]{\item[MATH #1] \emph{#2}\par #3}
\NewDocumentCommand\newcourse { m m m +m }{%
  \NewDocumentCommand #1 { s }{%
    \IfBooleanTF ##1 {%
      \stepcounter{hcourse}%
      \course{\tikzmark{\thehcourse a}#2}{#3}{#4}\tikzmark{\thehcourse b}%
      \tikz[remember picture, overlay]{%
        \foreach \i in {a,b} \coordinate (\thehcourse \i) at ({pic cs:\thehcourse \i});
        \draw [course highlight, line width=\courselinewidth] ($(\thehcourse a -| current page text area.west) + (-1em,\baselineskip)$) coordinate (\thehcourse c) -- ($(\thehcourse b -| \thehcourse c)$);
      }%
    }{%
      \course{#2}{#3}{#4}%
    }%
  }%
}
\NewDocumentCommand\coursehighlight { O {black} m }{%
  \colorlet{course highlight}{#1!#2}}
\newlength\courselinewidth
\setlength\courselinewidth{1pt}
\coursehighlight{75}
\newcourse{\sixten}{610}{A Course Title}{A long description \lipsum[5] Final words.}
\newcourse{\sixtwenty}{620}{Another Course Title}{A shorter description}

\begin{document}

\title{Course Offerings}
\author{}\date{}
\maketitle

\subsubsection*{Fall 2016}
\begin{description}
  \sixten
  \sixtwenty
\end{description}

\subsubsection*{Spring 2017}
\begin{description}
  \sixten*
  \sixtwenty
\end{description}

\coursehighlight[gray]{50}
\setlength\courselinewidth{1mm}
\begin{description}
  \sixten
  \sixtwenty*
\end{description}

In case you get a colour printer\dots
\coursehighlight[blue]{80}
\begin{description}
  \sixten*
  \sixtwenty
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

## Original Answer (Corrected)

Here's a way of boxing the course when a star is appended to the command. It requires defining new courses with `\newcourse` rather than `\newcommand`, but it involves less typing as an added bonus.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,tikz,tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcounter{hcourse}
\setcounter{hcourse}{0}
\newcommand{\course}[3]{\item[MATH #1] \emph{#2}\par #3}
\NewDocumentCommand\newcourse { m m m +m }{%
  \NewDocumentCommand #1 { s }{%
    \IfBooleanTF ##1 {%
      \stepcounter{hcourse}%
      \course{\tikzmark{\thehcourse a}#2}{#3}{#4}\tikzmark{\thehcourse b}%
      \tikz[remember picture, overlay]{%
        \foreach \i in {a,b} \coordinate (\thehcourse \i) at ({pic cs:\thehcourse \i});
        \draw ($(\thehcourse a -| current page text area.west) + (-1em,\baselineskip)$) rectangle ($(\thehcourse b -| current page text area.east) + (1em,-.5\baselineskip)$);
      }%
    }{%
      \course{#2}{#3}{#4}%
    }%
  }%
}
\newcourse{\sixten}{610}{A Course Title}{A long description \lipsum[5] Final words.}
\newcourse{\sixtwenty}{620}{Another Course Title}{A shorter description}
\begin{document}

\title{Course Offerings}
\author{}\date{}
\maketitle

\subsubsection*{Fall 2016}
\begin{description}
  \sixten
  \sixtwenty
\end{description}

\subsubsection*{Spring 2017}
\begin{description}
  \sixten*
  \sixtwenty
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image: new courses]

Comment: May be a little too much vertical padding at the bottom of the box? +1 for the star version

Comment: @Bernard It isn't actually padding. It is because the last line of the lipsum just fills the line. Is there a good way to avoid the additional line being added? If I remove the vertical space, it will cut through the last line of text in the majority of cases.

Comment: What part of the code senses whether or not there is a star? Is it the `{ s }`? And what does `{ m m m +m }` do? Edit: Is there something I should read to understand all this?

Comment: @cfr: Maybe a `%` at the end?

Comment: @Bernard `texdoc xparse` explains it. The `s` is a star. The `m m m +m` are 4 mandatory arguments: short, short, short, long. The `\IfBooleanTF` is testing whether there is a star or not when the command is called.

Comment: @Bernard I've got `lipsum[5]}`. If I put a comment, it'll miss the closing curly bracket! I think `lipsum` does this because if I add something afterwards, it seems there is additional spacing before the final words.

Comment: In the `leftbar` code, do you need `tikz`?

Comment: I mean, I know you used `tikzmark`, but couldn't the same result be achieved without tikz?

Comment: Ah... you didn't use `framed`.

Comment: @dejongbrent Indeed. I've never used that package. I used what I was familiar with. Bernard's solution is better. Well, the star thing is quite nice, I think. But you can combine that with Bernard's solution by just substituting his left bar code in for mine. And you don't need the counter in that case, either.

Comment: That's what I did. Thanks so much for your help (both @cfr and @Bernard)! I wish I could accept both answers.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Bernard, I have the following solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,framed}
\newcommand{\course}[3]{\item[MATH #1] \emph{#2}\newline{#3}}
\newcommand{\sixten}{\course{310}{A Course Title}{A long description \lipsum[5]}}
\newcommand{\sixtwenty}{\course{320}{Another Course Title}{A shorter description}}
\begin{document}
{\Large Course Offerings:}

Fall 2016
\begin{description}
\sixten
\sixtwenty
\end{description}
Spring 2017
\begin{description}
\begin{leftbar}
\sixten
\end{leftbar}
\sixtwenty
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]